# i tried to change path location in web.xml and also in html file <form action="../NewFile1.jsp">

Tags: html, eclipse, jsp

inside WebContent Creted 2 sub folders html and jsp inside html created index.html file and inside jsp created NewFile1.jsp.In this html file is running properly and is pointing to http://localhost:1234/project1/html/index.html correct path but when i click on button its pointing to html folder its not pointing to jsp folder http://localhost:1234/project1/html/WebContent/html/index.jsp?uname=jhjhj  .

Comment: Add some code and what you changed in web.xml?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>

 
<body>  
<form action="index.jsp">  
<input type="text" name="uname">  
<input type="submit" value="go"><br/>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html> 
this is my simple html code

Comment: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
welcome
</body>
</html> simple jsp code

Comment: Where is index,jsp file? If it is in html folder.
Try with  <form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/html/index.jsp">

Comment: i created two folders one is html and one is jsp  when i am trying to run the html file its working properly but after subbmit button its pointing the same html folder